# 7.1 surround sound by hdmi on windows 10 test and games not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, speakers, surround-sound

My problem is that Windows 10 doesn't play 7.1 surround sound instead it mixes sound into every speaker. When I test the speakers in the sound section it plays the same ding sound on every surround speaker (not on the specific one I click) even though I checked the 7.1 option.

My receiver (Harman Kardon AVR 460) shows Windows 10 input as Multi-Channel PCM (maybe this is the problem?). I tested my surround setup on other tests like the Dolby Digital Plus test or DTS and everything was working correctly. I am connected to my receiver by HDMI cable. I also checked every setting in the receiver and Windows 10 to make sure that there wasn't a speaker filling turned on. Movies with surround sound work but not games and Windows surround test.

Also, I want to add that I am connected by HDMI to my NVIDIA RTX 3060 graphics card.

Edit: I tested Surround on my other PC and everything was working correctly so it must be my PC problem.

Comment: How is the other PC connected to the receiver? Have you updated drivers?